# How is /dev/block/bootdevice/by-name created?

Tags: android, linux, yocto, busybox, toybox

I'm switching from `busybox` to `toybox` in a customized Yocto.
After the switch I no longer have `/dev/block/` populated.

I'd like to learn how `/dev/block/bootdevice/by-name` is populated?
Is this done by `mdev`?

The `toybox` `mdev` command is still in `pending`.
However, the `/dev/block/bootdevice/by-name` seems to be an Android feature which is using `toybox` irc.

Answer (score 2):

In Android there are a couple of parts to this:

1. `/dev/block/bootdevice` is created by an init script, for example [init.hardware.rc](https://android.googlesource.com/device/google/redbull/+/refs/tags/android-13.0.0_r24/init.hardware.rc#91):

   ```
   symlink /dev/block/platform/${ro.boot.boot_devices} /dev/block/bootdevice
   ```

   In this case the `ro.boot.boot_devices` property is derived from the kernel command line argument set when the kernel image is built by [BoardConfig-common.mk](https://android.googlesource.com/device/google/redbull/+/refs/tags/android-13.0.0_r24/BoardConfig-common.mk#48):

   ```
   BOARD_KERNEL_CMDLINE += androidboot.boot_devices=soc/1d84000.ufshc
   ```

   (All `androidboot.*` command line options are converted into `ro.boot.*` properties by `init`, see [`ProcessKernelCmdline()`](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/refs/tags/android-13.0.0_r24/init/property_service.cpp#1268)).
2. `/dev/block/platform/*` links are created by `ueventd` (which is part of the Android version of `init`). The function responsible for this is [DeviceHandler::GetBlockDeviceSymlinks()](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/system/core/+/refs/tags/android-13.0.0_r24/init/devices.cpp#368).

   This function is also responsible for creating the `/dev/block/platform/*/by-name` links based on the partition names supplied by the kernel in the uevent. Not all partition schemes supply a partition name, for example [GPT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table) does while a [DOS MBR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_boot_record) partition table does not.

   More recent versions of this function will also create generic links in `/dev/block/by-name` for partitions on the boot device. The boot device is again identified using the `androidboot.boot_devices` kernel command line option.